# Finding element occurring in each array in Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following array: `items = [[573, 574], [573, 574], [573], [573, 574]]`

How to find element which is occurring on each array ? From this array i want to get only "573"
Anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def appears_in_all(arr)
  arr.reduce(:&)
end

appears_in_all [[573, 574], [573, 574], [573], [573, 574]]           #=> [573]
appears_in_all [[573, 574], [573, 574], [573, 574, 578], [573, 574]] #=> [573, 574]
appears_in_all [[573, 574], [573, 574], [573], [573, 574], [2, 4]]   #=> []
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the smallest sub array in `items` (to limit the search set) and then select all the elements from that array that appear in all the other arrays in `items`:

```
items.min_by(&:length).select do |element|
  items.all? { |sub_array| sub_array.include?(element) }
end
# => [573]
```

if it's guaranteed only a single element is in all of them, you can use `detect` instead of `select`

Comment: I must use the comments to say is a very clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
items.flatten.uniq.select{|x| items.map{|y| y.include? x}.all?}
```